# Unable to locate folder xml under the civicrm root directory

Tags: drupal, extension, developer, civix

I am new to `civicrm` and trying to build extension. The extension is build and activated. The stage where I got stocked is when I trying to add `entity` for my `civicrm extension`. I am following the  [Official Documentation](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/#generate-entity) from the `civicrm` website.

Point **4.c** has mentioned to edit the file `<civiroot>/xml/schema/Schema.xml` but I am unable to file with that name and neither the path under the `<civiroot>`

**Please Note:** my `civicrm` root directory that I am following with `Drupal7` installation is as `<DruaplRoot>/sites/default/files/civicrm`

Please help to get out of this problem as I am unable to add new entity.

I'm thankful to you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like perhaps you are developing your extension within a normal CiviCRM installation instead of a *development* installation. If this is the case, you'll need to set up a development installation in order to get the `xml` folder (and other things too).

The best way to set up a development installation is to use the [civibuild](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/) tool which you will get if you install [buildkit](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/).

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to install buildkit using link you provided

Comment: I will let you know once finished