# How to create entity in CiviCRM

Tags: extension, developer, civix, civibuild

I am trying to create the Entity in CiviCRM with my extension. But I am struck here. Unable to find the XML folder in my CiviCRM installation. After running the below command `civix generate:entity MyEntity` nothing to do in the installed CiviCRM

[image]

I read the document and followed the steps. I strut in the below steps
https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/master/extensions/civix/

```
enter preformatted text here
```

[image]

I read these questions also none of the solutions helped

[How to automatically generate DAO classes for my DB tables](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3922/how-to-automatically-generate-dao-classes-for-my-db-tables)

[How do I add a new table to my extension?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/3534/how-do-i-add-a-new-table-to-my-extension?rq=1)

Please let me know is there any alternative way to create entity while creating an extension

Comment: Similar question: https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/19194/unable-to-locate-folder-xml-under-the-civicrm-root-directory

Answer (score 1):

It looks like like perhaps you are developing your extension within a normal CiviCRM installation instead of a *development* installation.  If this is the case, you'll need to set up a development installation in order to get the `xml` folder (and other things too).

The best way to set up a development installation is to use the [civibuild](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/) tool which you will get if you install [buildkit](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/buildkit/).

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I already installed buildkit; Could you please explain how to get development installation using this

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi read about the [civibuild](https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/tools/civibuild/) command. You will need to do something like: 

`civibuild create dmaster --url http://dmaster --type drupal-demo`

Comment: I installed civibuild and created the DAO file; And successfully run civix generate:upgrader; But I could not see any active links in Extentions page; Am I missed anything

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi for help with further questions and troubleshooting it would be best to either (1) got to the [developer chat room](https://chat.civicrm.org/civicrm/channels/dev) or (2) post a separate question here on StackExchange. I'd recommend that chat room for your right now, as it will allow for easier back-and-forth conversation.